# How to change a hypen to a period in a file and/or directory

Tags: bash, sed, awk, file-format

I'm trying to do this in linux/bash.  I have multiple directories.  I don't mind doing each one individually as there are just a few.  In each directory, there are files and folders with names like...

```
7-11 WSUS on workstations.png
7-12 1711-pen-FINAL-02_enc.pdf
12-12.txt
7-13.2 AD User selection.xlsx
7-14.2 Server selection.xlsx
7-14 it-vm21-1.png
12.14 it-vm21.png
7.14 Syslog message from 10-35-1-91.doc
7.14 Syslog message from 10-35-1-91.msg
7-16.2 admin request selection.xlsx
7-17.2 Employee hire selection.xlsx
7-17 Contractor List.xlsx
```

Initially, I would like this to only be for files, but would also like to know how to make it applicable to include directories if desired.  I would like to take the first hypen and replace it with a period so the above list would look like this.

```
7.11 WSUS on workstations.png
7.12 1711-pen-FINAL-02_enc.pdf
12.12.txt
7.13.2 AD User selection.xlsx
7.14.2 Server selection.xlsx
7.14 it-vm21-1.png
12.14 it-vm21.png
7.14 Syslog message from 10-35-1-91.doc
7.14 Syslog message from 10-35-1-91.msg
7.16.2 admin request selection.xlsx
7.17.2 Employee hire selection.xlsx
7.17 Contractor List.xlsx
```

Not sure where to begin.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rename` command, to rename everything:

```
rename -n 's/-/\./' *
```

For files:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rename -n 's/-/\./' {} +
```

For directories:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rename -n 's/-/\./' {} +
```

---

Remove the `-n` option from command when you was sure it would work for you.
You can also change `-maxdepth` according to your needs.

Comment: `find` finds recursively, that’s worth being mentioned. for directories without subdirectories: `rename -n 's/-/\./' */` – for everything in a subdirectory: `rename -n 's/-/\./' */*` – for directories in a subdirectory: `rename -n 's/-/\./' */*/`

Comment: @dessert Completely forgot about that... thanks.

Comment: I think OP wants `find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f` and `rename */*`: *I have multiple directories. (…) In each directory, there are files and folders (…) Initially, I would like this to only be for files, but would also like to know how to make it applicable to include directories if desired.*

Comment: I did try `find -type f -exec rename 's/-/\./' {} +`.  One of the results stated `Can't rename ./7-17 NewHireSample/John Doe.htm ./7.17 NewHireSample/John Doe.htm: No such file or directory`.  I know this is because the directory 7-17xxx was renamed to 7.17xxx before find got to the actual file.  How would you prevent the error or do you just have to pipe to stderr?

Comment: @user2616163 I'm not sure, try this: `find -type f -exec rename 's/-/\./' "{}" +`